# What is the optimal distribution of RAM across available slots given a specific amount?

Tags: memory, macbook, power, dual-channel

Given two memory slots, what is the optimal configuration given my 2x1GB, plus either 1x4GB or 2x2GB? (I just bought a used laptop with two slots, currently 2x1GB, max 8GB)

Possible upgrade combinations (assuming permutations aren't necessary -- does slot order matter?):
3GB = 1x2GB + 1x1GB
4GB = 1x4GB
4GB = 2x2GB
5GB = 1x4GB + 1x1GB
Which is my optimal configuration?

I am looking for clarification in these concepts (explanation why is appreciated):
a) Is 2x2GB better than 1x4GB?
b) Must the two slots have exactly the same capacity to gain the benefit?
c) How does 2x2GB = 4GB match up against 1x4GB + 1x1GB = 5GB?
d) Does 8GB max mean 4GB max per slot?
e) In theory, given the max 8GB, which of 1x8GB and 2x8GB would yield better performance?

Edit:
I looked into dual-channel memory and from my understanding it reduces the latency of some operations and allows for concurrency during others, resulting in a marked performance increase that is not possible with only one chip. (Thanks David)

Comment: There really are no ramifications to be honest.

Comment: If you don't have the same amount of RAM on each channel, you will lose dual channel. However, going from 2GB to 5GB is worth losing dual channel.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, if you are going for two different types of RAM  configuration dual channel won't be possible, thus lower performance 
The two slots must be exactly the same otherwise they will run with the speed of the lower specifications (or it might not even boot, which will mean you will have to manually set the same timings in the bios for it to post)

This is a tricky one, you get    double the bandwidth in dual channel mode, but you do lose 1GB of   memory, since you stated you have 8GB I would recommend getting one  4GB stick, save up some money and buy another identical stick.

Disregarding the limitation, more ram is better almost* all the time,    so go big.

2x2>1x4, 4+1>2x2 but 4x4>1x8

*It will depend on what you are using it for.

Answer (score 0):

a) Bigger is almost always better when everything else is the same as far as RAM goes.

b) To achieve Dual Channel mode you must:

- Have matching DIMM configuration in each channel
- Have matching density of RAM (1GB, 2GB, etc.)
- Be matched in both Channel A and Channel B memory channels (either color or parallel separated.)

  If any of these are not met it will revert to single channel mode for those channels.

  The following does not matter:
- Same brand
- Same timing specifications
- Same DDR speed

  Memory channel speed is determined by the slowest DIMM module populated in
  the system.

c) Review this article: [LINK](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/PARALLEL-PROCESSING,1705.html) that TomsHardware did about parallel processing (Single Channel configurations vs Dual Channel) back in 2007. It might be a little different today, but it's still a very good read.

d) It depends. Does it say 8GB Max per slot, or 8GB Max? If it's the former then your per slot maximum density can be 8GB. If it's the latter then your motherboard is limited to any configuration of densities up to 8GB.

e) Theoretically, your 2x4GB configuration will yield slightly better results than a 1x8GB. Anywhere from ~1-3%. TomsHardware test results: [LINK](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/PARALLEL-PROCESSING,1705-11.html). If you've got 1x8GB and 2x8GB as an option, always choose the 2x8 everything else being equal.